# Can't ssh to tryhackme server no matter what I do

Tags: ssh, openvpn

I've been having trouble connecting to tryhackme's SSH server from my Linux machine (Linux Mint 21.1 Cinnamon). The terminal displays a port 22 connection timeout error.

Here's the output from the terminal :

```shellsession
~$ ssh -vvv tryhackme@10.10.21.145
OpenSSH_8.9p1 Ubuntu-3ubuntu0.3, OpenSSL 3.0.2 15 Mar 2022
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 19: include /etc/ssh/ssh_config.d/*.conf matched no files
debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 21: Applying options for *
debug2: resolve_canonicalize: hostname 10.10.21.145 is address
debug3: expanded UserKnownHostsFile '~/.ssh/known_hosts' -> '/home/deus-ex/.ssh/known_hosts'
debug3: expanded UserKnownHostsFile '~/.ssh/known_hosts2' -> '/home/deus-ex/.ssh/known_hosts2'
debug3: ssh_connect_direct: entering
debug1: Connecting to 10.10.21.145 [10.10.21.145] port 22.
debug3: set_sock_tos: set socket 3 IP_TOS 0x10
debug1: connect to address 10.10.21.145 port 22: Connection timed out
ssh: connect to host 10.10.21.145 port 22: Connection timed out
```

How else can I troubleshoot this problem with my limited skillset ?

- I configured OopenVPN correctly and imported the `.ovpn` file from the site proper and it says I'm connected on the sites access page.
- I allowed SSH in `ufw` and allowed input and output chains. I messed with the SSH configuration file (the `ForwardX11` is set to `yes` and the `ForwardX11Trusted` is set to `no`).

**Edit :**

Here's the output when I load the `.ovpn` file:

```
2023-08-03 18:00:14 WARNING: Compression for receiving enabled. Compression has been used in the past to break encryption. Sent packets are not compressed unless "allow-compression yes" is also set.
2023-08-03 18:00:14 --cipher is not set. Previous OpenVPN version defaulted to BF-CBC as fallback when cipher negotiation failed in this case. If you need this fallback please add '--data-ciphers-fallback BF-CBC' to your configuration and/or add BF-CBC to --data-ciphers.
2023-08-03 18:00:14 OpenVPN 2.5.5 x86_64-pc-linux-gnu [SSL (OpenSSL)] [LZO] [LZ4] [EPOLL] [PKCS11] [MH/PKTINFO] [AEAD] built on Jul 14 2022
2023-08-03 18:00:14 library versions: OpenSSL 3.0.2 15 Mar 2022, LZO 2.10
2023-08-03 18:00:14 Outgoing Control Channel Authentication: Using 512 bit message hash 'SHA512' for HMAC authentication
2023-08-03 18:00:14 Incoming Control Channel Authentication: Using 512 bit message hash 'SHA512' for HMAC authentication
2023-08-03 18:00:14 TCP/UDP: Preserving recently used remote address: [AF_INET]18.202.129.195:1194
2023-08-03 18:00:14 Socket Buffers: R=[212992->212992] S=[212992->212992]
2023-08-03 18:00:14 UDP link local: (not bound)
2023-08-03 18:00:14 UDP link remote: [AF_INET]18.202.129.195:1194
2023-08-03 18:00:14 TLS: Initial packet from [AF_INET]18.202.129.195:1194, sid=f8b4add2 9b69173d
```

**Edit 2:**
Here's the ouptputs for ip a and ip r respectively :

```
~$ ip a
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
    inet 127.0.0.1/8 scope host lo
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 ::1/128 scope host 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
2: wlan0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc mq state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether a0:2c:36:6c:c1:8b brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 192.168.1.36/24 brd 192.168.1.255 scope global dynamic noprefixroute wlan0
       valid_lft 83529sec preferred_lft 83529sec
    inet6 fe80::4d74:a228:6906:4be8/64 scope link noprefixroute 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
3: tun0: <POINTOPOINT,MULTICAST,NOARP,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc fq_codel state UNKNOWN group default qlen 500
    link/none 
    inet 10.8.0.1/24 scope global tun0
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 fe80::444c:446f:76:8869/64 scope link stable-privacy 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
4: tun1: <POINTOPOINT,MULTICAST,NOARP,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc fq_codel state UNKNOWN group default qlen 500
    link/none 
    inet 10.8.154.178/16 scope global tun1
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 fe80::767f:df32:bb7:fbe1/64 scope link stable-privacy 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
```

```
~$ ip r
default via 192.168.1.1 dev wlan0 proto dhcp metric 600 
10.8.0.0/24 dev tun0 proto kernel scope link src 10.8.0.1 
10.8.0.0/16 dev tun1 proto kernel scope link src 10.8.154.178 
10.10.0.0/16 via 10.8.0.1 dev tun0 metric 1000 
169.254.0.0/16 dev wlan0 scope link metric 1000 
192.168.1.0/24 dev wlan0 proto kernel scope link src 192.168.1.36 metric 600
```

**Edit 3:**
Here's what I get after pinging :

```
ping -c3 10.10.21.145
PING 10.10.93.154 (10.10.93.154) 56(84) bytes of data.

--- 10.10.93.154 ping statistics ---
3 packets transmitted, 0 received, 100% packet loss, time 2043ms
```

**Edit 4:**
Here's my routing table :

```
Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
0.0.0.0         192.168.1.1     0.0.0.0         UG    600    0        0 wlan0
10.8.0.0        0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 tun0
10.8.0.0        0.0.0.0         255.255.0.0     U     0      0        0 tun1
10.8.0.0        0.0.0.0         255.255.0.0     U     0      0        0 tun2
10.10.0.0       10.8.0.1        255.255.0.0     UG    1000   0        0 tun0
169.254.0.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.0.0     U     1000   0        0 wlan0
192.168.1.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     600    0        0 wlan0
```

Comment: You command `ssh tryhackme@10.10.21.145` refers to a non-routable address.   See https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/non-routable-address-space/

Comment: I know nothing about the challenge, but in the text & tags you mention openvpn; can you please add the output of `ip a` just before you try to ssh to your question [that is: edit the question and post the output there, it becomes unreadable in comments]?

Comment: I load .ovpn file using the terminal and then I check if I have access in the tryhackme website (edit : I added the output after loading the file).

Comment: I'd like to see the output of `ip a` and `ip r`, respectively. That vpn output doesn't tell us enough ...

Comment: Try pinging the server in question to test routing: `ping -c3 10.10.21.145`.  Look at the packet loss.  (Not all computers respond to pings but it's a common connection test.)

Comment: Did you set up **two** VPNs instead of one? Your routing table looks... interesting.

Comment: @dirkt what do you mean by interesting, care to elaborate ?.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know what the problem but I solved it by uninstalling OpenVpn and purging all related files then installing it again (reinstall doesn't work).

Thanks for the constructive feedback and the tips.

Comment: So you probably had some configuration files that did cause it to open two VPNs... if you look at your routes, you had overlapping routes for 10.8.x.x, one /24 via the first tunnel interface, and a /16 via the second interface. Also note that this is a typical "it's not what I thought it was" question, contrary to the information in your question you didn't configure OpenVPN correctly (or rather, you configure it twice "correctly"). So it's a good idea no to make assumptions about what is working and what is not working.